# Open terminal via Safari

Tags: terminal, safari

Is it possible to open a terminal window from a Safari webpage?
I have found a way to open a ssh terminal window, but is it possible to only open the terminal window without pre filled commands?

I have tried to search on google but i only find solutions for opening Safari from terminal.

To open terminal with ssh from Safari i put the following link on a webpage:

`<a href="ssh://adminuser@10.225.xxx.xxx">ssh</a>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three URL types which can open Terminal from Safari:

1. `ssh`
2. `telnet`
3. `x-man-page`

Those informations can be found under `CFBundleURLTypes` key in: `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/Info.plist`

So in order to open Terminal app, you can place link like:

`<a href="telnet://">telnet</a>`

`<a href="ssh://">ssh</a>`

`<a href="x-man-page://">man page</a>`

It does not prefill informations in Terminal for me.

---

Bonus:
This rule can be applied to any application that can open URLs.

Check URL types of the app with:

`defaults read /absolute/path/to/Info.plist CFBundleURLTypes`

for example:

`defaults read /Applications/Utilities/Script\ Editor.app/Contents/Info.plist CFBundleURLTypes`

This gives me `applescript` as URL type, so making link like:

`<a href="applescript://">Script Editor</a>`

Opens the Script Editor app.

Comment: New location `/System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`